# filp_open in Linux kernel device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

filp_open allows us to open a file in the file system. But is it safe to use from Kernel space ? If used what needs to be taken care. Will this be supported in future versions of Linux kernel as well.

Currently using 2.6.28 Linux kernel version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of drivers use the filp_open() function, it is pretty much a helper *to open a file in kernelspace*. No reason to assume it won't continue to be supported. Even the kernel's filesystem subsystem uses filp_open().